# Scrolling broken on all touch devices - Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I came across a parallax page that uses a couple of plugins (and Wordpress - ugh) that works fine on desktops, but when viewed on a mobile device or in Device Mode with Chrome Inspector, all scrolling is prevented. I've noticed that `overflow: hidden` is added to a couple of parent containers, but even with those removed scrolling is prevented.

http://insigniamquarterly.com/infographics/by-the-numbers/

Any ideas on how to prevent the screen from being locked?

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but did you want to ask a question ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because of the `overflow: hidden`

Add this to fix.

```
html, body {
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```